# Is it worth to write a custom Profile Provider?

Tags: asp.net

I wrote a custom Membership Provider and it was relatively easy.

Now I need to create users with first name, last name and other fields not considered in the any of the MembershipProvider.CreateUser overloads.

I read that I should not overload CreateUser. Instead, I should write my own Profile Provider.

It seems like a lot of work and I am not sure of the benefits. Can you help me decide the right way to go? (It is for a MVC 3.0 web app.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If it isn't a lot of info, you could just create a custom MembershipUser class with the appropriate additional fields. You can look at codeplex.com to find examples of custom Profile implementations.

Comment: Hi Peter I recognize your name from eggheadcafe.com -thank you for your answer and basically for teaching me .NET!